# Feeding Access Token into list_folder method, Dropbox API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm making a small python script to list all files recursively within a user's Dropbox account. The OAuth2.0 flow works, but I am frankensteining in another call to the list_folder method to list those files/folders.

I'm stuck at like 22 where I need to provide the access token returned by the OAuth flow. What can I call to return the token?

(Or, do you know of a quick python script that already does what I am asking)

```
from dropbox.client import DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect, DropboxClient
from dropbox import rest as dbrest
import requests
import json

auth_flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect('<APP_KEY>', '<APP_SECRET>')
###These are filled out in my code, but I hid them here.

authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
print "1. Go to: " + authorize_url
print "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)."
print "3. Copy the authorization code."
auth_code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

try:
    oauth_result = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
except dbrest.ErrorResponse, e:
    print('Error: %s' % (e,))

url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {
    "path": "",
    "recursive": True,
    "include_media_info": True,
    "include_deleted": True
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python), you don't need to make the HTTP POST request manually like you're attempting.

You can get the access token from the app authorization flow, and make a Dropbox client, as shown in the [`DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect` documentation](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.oauth.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect).

Then, you can call [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder) [as shown in this example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L137), (and [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue) if [`ListFolderResult.has_more`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.files.ListFolderResult.has_more) was `True`).